# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in ORACLE 10G

Tags: sql, oracle, runtime-error, oracle10g

I was creating a table, however it keep giving me the error.

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

My code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMP (
    ENO CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ENAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    JOB_TYPE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MANAGER CHAR(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    DNO INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
    COMMISSION DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    SALARY DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DNO FOREIGN KEY (DNO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DNO),
    CONSTRAINT MANAGER FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER) REFERENCES EMP(ENO)
);
```

Comment: Several suggestions, if I may: `char(n)` is very rarely needed or helpful; you will find that `varchar2(n)` is almost always better. Then: in the Oracle world, it's much better to use `varchar2(n)` rather than `varchar(n)` - it's best to not even ask why. And, for numbers, it is best to learn to use the Oracle standard data type `number(m, n)`. Instead of `integer(11)` use `number(11,0)`, and `number(7,2)` instead of `decimal(7, 2)`, etc.

Comment: I see also that there are two downvotes on this question. The bad thing is that the monkeys who downvoted a perfectly valid question didn't feel it necessary to state their objection to it. Perhaps the question is too basic, perhaps they wanted you to "read the documentation", whatever - at least leave a note as to what they thought was wrong, so others can opine on their objection. Don't get discouraged; the help you can get on this site will more than make up for the annoyances you have to put up with.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove *size* for integer (`DNO` column):

```
SQL> select * from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi

SQL> CREATE TABLE EMP
  2  (
  3     ENO         CHAR (3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  4     ENAME       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  5     JOB_TYPE    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  6     MANAGER     CHAR (3) DEFAULT NULL,
  7     HIRE_DATE   DATE NOT NULL,
  8     DNO         INTEGER NOT NULL,
  9     COMMISSION  DECIMAL (10, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
 10     SALARY      DECIMAL (7, 2) NOT NULL,
 11     CONSTRAINT DNO FOREIGN KEY (DNO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS (DNO),
 12     CONSTRAINT MANAGER FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER) REFERENCES EMP (ENO)
 13  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: You should accept the answer if it worked for you so that this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: The diagnosis is correct, but the cure - in my opinion - is not the best one. If the OP had a good reason to limit the size of integers to 11 digits, then the better choice is not to use `integer` (with no limit on size), but `number(11,0)`.

Comment: @mathguy . . . In MySQL (which supports the syntax and is presumably the cause of confusion), `int(11)` does not specify the number of digits being stored.  It simply specifies the display width for the value.